# Multiplying a named vector of numbers by a single number in R

Tags: r, function, dataframe, vector

In my code below, `m3$modelStruct$varStruct` returns a named vector of numbers. But when I multiply that by `sigma(m3)^2`, the multiplication doesn't happen. Is there a fix for this?

```
library(nlme)

dat <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/e/master/var.csv')
dat$fmonth <- factor(dat$month)


vf2 <- varIdent(form= ~ 1 | fmonth)

m3 <- lme(y ~ x*fmonth, random = ~1|id, data = dat,
              weights = vf2)


sigma(m3)^2 * m3$modelStruct$varStruct   ## PROBLEM IS HERE!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your premises of `m3$modelStruct$varStruct` being a named vector is incorrect. Your multiplication returns an object of

```
class(sigma(m3)^2 * m3$modelStruct$varStruct)
#[1] "varIdent" "varFunc"
```

Thus, the print method `print.varFunc` is invoked.

If you actually want to multiply with the values displayed by `print(m3$modelStruct$varStruct)`, you need to extract the coefficients:

```
m3$modelStruct$varStruct
#Variance function structure of class varIdent representing
#        5         6         9        10        12         3         4        11         8         2         1         7 
#1.0000000 1.0065306 1.8362431 1.3632609 0.7827463 1.2128426 0.8708676 0.9233713 0.6003184 0.6064313 1.2060820 0.8399081


sigma(m3)^2 * coef(m3$modelStruct$varStruct, uncons = FALSE, allCoef = TRUE)
#       5        6        9       10       12        3        4       11        8        2        1        7 
#4.292699 4.320733 7.882439 5.852068 3.360094 5.206368 3.738372 3.963755 2.576986 2.603227 5.177347 3.605472
```